# How can I move catalina.out with log4j in Azure blob storage

Tags: log4j, azure-blob-storage, tomcat8, catalina.out

How this can be achieve? I have a catalina.out log in a prod server which is growing fast in space. 6.7 GB in couple of days . I had the Idea at the begging to create a cronjob to be executed 2 or 3 days a week to run a script that copy catalina log to Azure blob storage and then wipe it out with just a command "echo "" > file".  But moving 2 GB to azure every day  that cron job executes don´t know if is the best idea either. way too big file.
Is there a way that the logs is in another server/azure storage? Where should I configuer that? 
I read something about implementing log4j with tomcat, is this possible also? that catalina.out using log4j move it to other server? Howcan I achieve this?. I know that development team should check also why is growing and logging so fast this file, but in the meantime I need a solution to implement.

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> I read something about implementing log4j with tomcat, is this
>   possible also?

I think what you want to describe is `Log Rotation`, if you want to use this way, here is a [blog](http://blog.kchandrahasa.com/blog/2013/07/16/configuring-tomcat-catalina-log-rotation/) about how to configure it.

> I had the Idea at the begging to create a cronjob to be executed 2 or
>   3 days a week to run a script that copy catalina log to Azure blob
>   storage

Yes, you could choose this way to manage log, however I still have something to say. If you want to upload the log file to Azure Blob, I think you may get error for the large file . You need split large file into multiple small file. In this [article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-4-uploading-large-blobs/), under the title **Upload a file in blocks programmatically**, there is detailed description.

From you description, you are not using Azure Web, so if you choose Azure Web , you could also use `Azure Functions` or `WebJobs` to do the cronjob.

If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: isn´t it Webjobs for webapps? this is a server VM in azure. Also yes I will have to implement something with log4j to rotate logs to Azure blobs, do you think I can do that? didn´t found much in the itnernet for doing it.

Comment: @Valebian yes, webjob is a function under azure webapps, if you still want to manage logs manually, you could choose Azure Function.

Comment: yeap that for log rotation, but need to know specific how to configure log4j it for log rotation and to move it to azure. Will let you know, thanks